# How to add multiple pages home screen icon in PWA

Tags: wordpress, manifest, amp-html, progressive-web-apps

I need help to add multiple home screen icon on single website also on single domain. I've manifest.json file + services work also installing but home screen icon not showing on multiple pages.

What I need to do now to create multiple home screen icon for each page?

Thanks in advance to seniors.

Comment: Check the 'scope' attribute in manifest.

Comment: @RickySpanish Can you please help me to add home screen icons for page in single domain

Comment: Here is a [sample app](https://nebula-cross.glitch.me/) that demonstrates multiple installable pages in a single domain.

Comment: Abraham, I have the exact same structure as your example, one top manifest and 2 in subfolders. However if I add the top manifest first, then I can´t add the ones in subfolders, then it thinks that it is already installed. But if I first install the 2 in the subfolders and last the top one, then I can install all 3. Can you install in any order with yours?

Comment: I just tested yours and it the same problem, if you add the top level you can´t install the ones in the subfolders.